# How to convert 52:34 string value to bigint

Tags: string, postgresql, casting, bigint

How to cast a value `52:35` which is stored as a string in the DB and I want only `52` in BigInt value in PostgreSQL DB as a query.

I tried with this following query

```
select cast(substr(a,1,strpos(a,':')-1) AS bigint) as value from abc
```

which returned me an error     "negative substring length not allowed"

Comment: Why the `java` tag ? is it valid to do the parsing in java ? This is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

That query will fail when it encounters a value that does not contain a colon `:`.   Use a `case...when...else...end` construct to attempt the extraction only when the value contains a colon. Something like (untested)

```
CASE WHEN strpos(a,':') > 0 
    THEN cast(substr(a,1,strpos(a,':')-1) AS bigint
    else null
END
```

For the `else` case, substitute whatever you need.  There might also be a way to use `split_part(...)` instead of the above, but I had trouble finding documentation saying what happens if the delimiter is not present.

Comment: For `split_part` when there is no delimiter and you take first field then it will return whole string.

Comment: Thanku Jim Garrison,,,,the above query part worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#idm46428710560224)

```
postgres=# select split_part('52:35', ':', 1)::bigint;
 split_part
------------
         52

postgres=# select split_part('52', ':', 1)::bigint;
 split_part
------------
         52
```